# only called avicap32 once c#

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, photo

I wrote a c# program to take a photo by webcam using .net framework 2.0. I tried to use avicap32.dll to call the webcam.

The problem is i can just call my webcam once, if i disconnect the web cam and start it again via some buttons, then picturebox will show a black photo and cannot call the webcam again. if i restart the program again it will keep black in the picture box. Only if I restart my computer. W.T.F. Any one can solve the problem?

I put the source code below. Trying figure out what's going on. Another broblem is the photo shows in picture box cannot set the central of the image as well.

here's the form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace AutoCam
{
    public partial class form1 : Form
    {

        public form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Camera camera;

        #region InitializeComponent

        #region btn_openCamera #endregion
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.btn_openCamera.Enabled = false;
            this.btn_closeCam.Enabled = true;
            this.btn_cameraPic.Enabled = true;
            camera = new Camera(this.pic_camera.Handle, this.pic_camera.Width, this.pic_camera.Height);
            camera.StartWebCam();
        }
        #endregion

        #region btn_closeCam_Click
        private void btn_closeCam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.btn_openCamera.Enabled = true;
            this.btn_closeCam.Enabled = false;
            this.btn_cameraPic.Enabled = false;
            camera.CloseWebcam();
        }
        #endregion

        #region btn_cameraPic_Click
        private void btn_cameraPic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            camera.GrabImage(this.pic_camera.Handle, "guying.bmp");
        }
        #endregion

        private void quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

here's the camera.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace AutoCam
{

    class Camera
    {
    private IntPtr lwndC;
        private IntPtr mControlPtr;
        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;

        public Camera(IntPtr handel, int width, int height)
        {
            mControlPtr = handel; //handle of video dom
            mWidth = width; //video width
            mHeight = height; //video height
        }

        public void StartWebCam()
        {
            byte[] lpszName = new byte[100];
            byte[] lpszVer = new byte[100];
            CameraAPI.capGetDriverDescriptionA(0, lpszName,100, lpszVer, 0);
            this.lwndC = CameraAPI.capCreateCaptureWindowA(lpszName, CameraAPI.WS_CHILD | CameraAPI.WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight, mControlPtr, 0);
            if (CameraAPI.SendMessage(lwndC, CameraAPI.WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0))
            {
                CameraAPI.SendMessage(lwndC, CameraAPI.WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 100, 0);
                CameraAPI.SendMessage(lwndC, CameraAPI.WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, true, 0);
            }
        }

        public void CloseWebcam()
        {
            CameraAPI.SendMessage(lwndC, CameraAPI.WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
        }

        public void GrabImage(IntPtr hWndC, string path)
        {
            IntPtr hBmp = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(path);
            CameraAPI.SendMessage(lwndC, CameraAPI.WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, hBmp.ToInt32());
        }

    }

}
```

here's the cameraAPI.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace AutoCam
{
    class CameraAPI
    {
        [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr capCreateCaptureWindowA(byte[] lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hWndParent, int nID);
        [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
        public static extern bool capGetDriverDescriptionA(short wDriver, byte[] lpszName, int cbName, byte[] lpszVer, int cbVer);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, bool wParam, int lParam);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, short wParam, int lParam);

        public const int WM_USER = 0x400;
        public const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
        public const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        public const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
        public const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
        public const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT = WM_USER + 10;
        public const int WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT = WM_USER +11;
        public const int WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_FRAME = WM_USER +5;
        public const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = WM_USER+50;
        public const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWFORMAT = WM_USER + 45;
        public const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE = WM_USER + 52;
        public const int WM_CAP_START = WM_USER;
        public const int WM_CAP_SAVEDIB = WM_CAP_START + 25;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [blog](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Webcam-Capture-50295c7f), and modify your code. I have tried the code, which worked well.
click stop:

```
            bStopped = true;
            this.timer.Stop();

            Application.DoEvents();

            SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);

            CloseClipboard();
```

click start:

```
        stop();

        m_CapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, this.Handle.ToInt32(), 0);

        Application.DoEvents();

        SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0);

        this.timer.Interval = 1;

        bStopped = false;
        this.timer.Start();
```

timer callback:

```
        this.timer.Stop();

        SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_GT_FRAME, 0, 0);

        SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_COPY, 0, 0);

        OpenClipboard(m_CapHwnd);

        CloseClipboard();

        IDataObject dataObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        Image img = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)dataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
        //img.Save("e:\\test_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks + ".jpg");
        pictureBox.Image = img;

        pictureBox.Refresh();

        Application.DoEvents();

        if (!bStopped)
        {
            this.timer.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Archive link to blog (https://web.archive.org/web/20150908103322/https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Webcam-Capture-50295c7f) and download (https://web.archive.org/web/20150921193359/https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Webcam-Capture-50295c7f/file/79390/4/Webcam%20Capture.zip)